# What is the optimal Tech I sub-capital ship and fit to defeat an Amarr Interceptor?

Tags: eve-online

Recently, my two-person corp has been [war-dec](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/War_Declaration)ed by a one man corp run by [xManBearPiggx](http://gate.eveonline.com/Profile/xManBearPiggx) who often attacks with either of the [Amarr Interceptors](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Item_Database:Ships:Frigates:Advanced_Frigates:Interceptors:Amarr) (or occasionally with a [Catalyst](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Catalyst)).

To my great shame he's been able to take out a couple of my [cheap cargo frigates](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Probe). So I've decided to hunt or ambush my assailant.  The only problem is that I'm about a year behind my opponent in character skills, so I can't really use tech II or higher ships or fits.

But what I lack in character skills I can make for with a large trade income, so I'm trying to figure out how to buy my way out of this problem.  I'm not rich enough that I could afford faction ships, but I can afford just about any Tech I ship. Also,  I have a fair mixture of combat and piloting skills so it wouldn't take long to train for any of the Tech I ships.

So I'm wondering what is the optimal fit to take on a pirate in an Amarr Interceptor with [tech 2 dual light pulse lasers](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Dual_Light_Pulse_Laser_II)?

Comment: questions like this make me want to start playing eve again so badly!

Comment: Do not delete tags without starting a discussion on it, I will rollback.  I challenge the notion that tags must follow some special plan, such that new tags aren't allowed.

Comment: In that case, I challenge your notion of the use of the fitting tag.  Obviously, it's for questions about [fitting Tetris blocks into the correct position](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3LCZi.png).  (Or maybe *meta tags are just bad*)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is difficult to give you a definitive answer given that situations vary so much in *EVE*, all you can do is try to stack cards in your favor.

Some things to consider though:

1. Interceptors survive on speed, get a Warp Scrambler, hopefully you can use it (possibly overheated) to turn off their MWD which will lend you a huge advantage.
2. Remember Lasers do EM and Therm damage only, tank for it
3. Amarr are armor tanks, which makes them vulnerable to Kinetic/explosive. He probably doesn't have *that* much to plug that hole.
4. Personally I would look into destroyers, they hit hard, recently were buffed, and fit with tracking mods can probably hit the quick bastard.
5. Failing that, get friends, or starve him until he goes away.

Fly Safe!

Answer (score 1):

Is the second man in your corp an actual second account/person or just an alt?

If so you could use the 2nd account to support the first with either

- a second combat ship,
- a boat bonused for electronic warfare like jammers (e.g the Griffin I think the boat is called) or tracking disruption (Crusader I think?), or
- remote repping your first boat with a well tanked cruiser. Remember that repping boats not specifically bonused for it will only have a short rep range (~6 km or so) so the combat ship would have to either stay within range or the repper would need to be able to keep up.

Of all of those options having both characters fight in combat boats would be most fun I think. A couple of thrashers or Rifters perhaps?

Comment: -.- apparently my smartphone doesn't like to format bullet points...

Comment: The issue was just a missing blank line before your bulleted list (the quirks of markdown...)

Comment: It's a live human in this case, so i'll probably try something like you suggest.

Comment: Having a person wardec you in high sec without ridiculously outnumbering you is actually a rare treat. You should definitely try and fight him where you can, you'll likely lose to start with, but you'll have a lot of fun learning

Answer (score 1):

Fit a Thrasher with autocannons and load Phased plasma, fit a microwarp drive, warps scram, and a stasis web.  then get a friend to fly an osprey with a bunch of medium shield transfers. put a damage control and a tracking enhancer in the lows